# unable to see kjhtml report when running jasmine tests

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine

I'm using jasmine with karma to unit test angular components. I'm not able to see html report that shows test results for all the components rather i'm seeing html document of each component when it executes that component's unit tests. What is the configuration i need to do to get the unit test results in browser as kjhtml report. Also my tests are running infinite number of time, how should i configure karma to execute tests only once.

below is my karma-config.json file

```
  module.exports = function (config) {
  config.set({
    basePath: '',
    frameworks: ['jasmine', '@angular/cli'],
    plugins: [
      require('karma-jasmine'),
      require('karma-chrome-launcher'),
      require('karma-jasmine-html-reporter'),
      require('karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter'),
      require('@angular/cli/plugins/karma')
    ],
    client: {
      clearContext: false // leave Jasmine Spec Runner output visible in browser
    },
    htmlReporter: {
      outputFile: 'reports/ut/index.html',
      pageTitle: 'Unit Tests',
      subPageTitle: 'SR-Dashboard',
      groupSuites: true,
      useCompactStyle: true,
      useLegacyStyle: true
    },
    coverageIstanbulReporter: {
      reports: ['html', 'lcovonly'],
      fixWebpackSourcePaths: true
    },
    angularCli: {
      environment: 'dev'
    },
    reporters: ['progress', 'kjhtml'],
    port: 9876,
    colors: true,
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
    autoWatch: true,
    browsers: ['Chrome'],
    singleRun: false
  });
};
```

Answer (score 1):

To run test and exit, you have to make following change:

```
// if true, Karma runs tests once and exits
singleRun: true
```

currently its set false in you config which makes it running infinite.

## regarding kjhtml report not printed in browser

its working fine for me with same configuration except following one. I did not put below code in karma config as it requires different plugin which is not included.

`htmlReporter: {
      outputFile: 'reports/ut/index.html',
      pageTitle: 'Unit Tests',
      subPageTitle: 'SR-Dashboard',
      groupSuites: true,
      useCompactStyle: true,
      useLegacyStyle: true
    },`